# Access data variable inside a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I made a repository of Vue using

> vue init webpack my-app

Now, my `main.js` is something like this --

// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.component('todo-item', {
  template: '<li>{{ todo }}</li>',
  props: ['todo']
})

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App :groceryList="groceryList"/>',
  data:{
    message: 'abcdefghi',
    groceryList: [
      { id: 0, text: 'Vegetables' },
      { id: 1, text: 'Cheese' },
      { id: 2, text: 'Whatever else humans are supposed to eat' }
    ]
  }
})
```

My `App.vue` file has the template with id `app` as mentioned in the main.js

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    At Parent: {{ groceryList[1].text }}
    <br/>
    <div>{{ message }}</div>
    <router-view/>
    <Table/>
    <Users/>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Users from './components/Users'
import Table from './components/Table'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Users,
    Table,
  },
}
</script>
```

Here,I keep getting errors that `cannot read property groceryList and message of undefined`. I have read the documentation of vue and according to it I am not making any mistakes. So, what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main.js`, you should declare `data` as a function and pass `:message` to App component

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App :groceryList="groceryList" :message="message"/>',
  data () {
    return {
      message: 'abcdefghi',
      groceryList: [
        { id: 0, text: 'Vegetables' },
        { id: 1, text: 'Cheese' },
        { id: 2, text: 'Whatever else humans are supposed to eat' }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

and in `App.vue`, you need to declare `groceryList` and `message` as props

```
<script>
import Users from './components/Users'
import Table from './components/Table'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  props: ['message', 'groceryList']
  components: {
    Users,
    Table,
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's one single component, why do I need to pass data as props? @ittus

Comment: They are 2 different components, one is `App.vue`, another is your `new Vue` main component

Comment: If I have to pass the same grocery list to Table component, how will it be done?

Comment: `<Table :groceryList="groceryList"/>`, remember to declare `groceryList` as prop in `Table` component.